# store.getState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

getting this issue that me and my peers are banging our heads against the table with. Uploaded to codesandbox to solve any issues.

rewriting the application twice, environment changes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/astillo/Car-Sales/tree/alexander-stillo

TypeError
store.getState is not a function

expecting the page to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove the `store` prop from  the`App` component

```
<AdditionalFeatures store={props.store} />
```

`AdditionalFeatures` will fetch it anyway from the store:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    store: state.store,
    car: state.car
  }
}
```

What was the issue? `react-redux` will use it to replace the redux store, [from 7.0](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1):

> Return of store as a Prop
>
> We've brought back the ability to pass a store as a prop directly to
>   connected components. This was removed in version 6 due to internal
>   implementation changes (components no longer subscribed to the store
>   directly). Some users expressed concerns that working with context in
>   unit tests was not sufficient. Since our components use direct
>   subscriptions again, we've reimplemented this option, and that should
>   resolve those concerns.